# qt/Mac: dSYM file for a release build

Tags: macos, qt

Is it possible to generate a DSYM file during a release build with Qt (4.7.4)? Any special directive I should be putting into my *.pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, and the directive is:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK='/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil <path to bundle> -o <output name.dsym>
```

Taken from [Qt Bugreports](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16549). But I tried it a while ago and it worked fine (that was under Leopard with 4.7.4)

Comment: Thanks. will try that shortly!